# How to access the Application gateway standard v2 ip in private using azure virtual network gateway?

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-network, azure-application-gateway, azure-vpn, network-security-groups

I need to host my application to limited trusted audience. I'm using application gateway standard v2 as my load balancer. I want to provide access to the application gateway those who are connected to my vpn. I created network security group and I configured inbound rules to restrict the public access of port 80.Also I'm trying to open the port 80 for my specific users.  But I couldn't able to configure source ip address range as dynamic based on vpn users.

**Following things I have tried**

1. I tried by adding vpn address pool as NSG inbound rule source address
2. I tried configuring the source tag as virtual network
3. I tried configuring my VPN address pool range in my NSG(app gateway subnet)

But no luck. If I'm hardcoding specific public ip address it's working. I couldn't able to configure this for my vpn users.

Anyone kindly advise me on this ?

Comment: Usually VPN users receive an internal private IP. This should be the IP you need to whitelist. Not to forget, usually you need to split-tunnel the traffic to make sure when the VPN is enabled that it catches the traffic towards the destination. Otherwise the clients the users are working on will simply send the traffic across the internet. Ofcourse your network also needs to make sure it routes the traffic accordingly. I'd say none of these things actually have anything to do with your Virtual Network Gateway.

Comment: Thanks @Marco for the quick turnaround.  Is it possible to whitelist vpn ipaddress in network security groups ? Any suggestion to capture that temp private ips ?

Comment: If they are temporary, no. Usually VPN solutions have a pool of IPs which get assigned to clients. Then you could whitelist this range. A network security group allows you to whitelist any IP, so I don't quite understand that question.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I already tried whitelisting the VPN address range pool also. But still my NSG not allowing to access my application.

Answer (score 0):

•   I would suggest you to please configure the whitelisting of client IP address range in the Microsoft VPN gateway that you may have configured. As the application gateway that you are using is configured to be used as a load balancer and not an IP filtering appliance. The application gateway has a private IP address assigned to it while the VPN gateway has a public IP address assigned to it due to which the users connecting to the VPN gateway will be redirected internally to the application gateway and then to the application hosted behind it for better availability.

Please refer the below screenshot for bypassing a set of client address pool through a VPN gateway: -
[image: VPN Gateway address pool]

Also, please check that the port ranges allowed or bypassed for the NSG of the application gateway can be filtered through it since it is purpose specific to port allow/disallow only.
Thus, for client address range to be allowed for a particular port in NSG of the application gateway, ensure that the inbound port rules for VPN gateway public IP address and the respective client IP address pool is also allowed for the respective port configured on the listener of the application gateway, i.e., 80 or 443.

But it is recommended that you configure them in the VPN gateway configuration.
[image: Application gateway NSG]

Please find the below link for reference regarding the application gateway: -

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/configuration-infrastructure#allow-access-to-a-few-source-ips